# Using SQL Server Database View for populating DataGridView and modifying data in DB

Tags: c#, database, winforms

**Using SQL Server Database View for populating DataGridView and modifying data in DB**

`I want to know that how this will be done and if this is not a good solution, then please elaborate if any other good solution is possible`.

---

1) Initially I want to use a `Database View` for populating different `DataGridViews`.

2) `Multiple joins from multiple tables` are required for the data-retrieval for each individual `DataGridView`.

3) The values from these `DataGridViews` are then populated in `Controls` (i.e. Textboxes/Combo-boxes) (For reference please see the images at this link:  [link text](http://rapidshare.com/files/399248066/Images.zip.html)).

4) When the User changes the values in `Controls`, and clicks `Save`, the data earlier retrieved from `DataGridView` (via `View`) is to be updated in the `Database`.

---

NOTE:I am working on C-Sharp Windows Application and using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Any answer to my above question ? I am still waiting for an earliest reply.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure how you can bind a control directly to a View, but you can edit your DataSet (assuming your using the designer under data sources right click on your dataset and click "edit dataset in designer", once there you can right click and add a table adapter which you can populate however you want (For example

```
   SELECT * FROM [YourView]
```

Alternatively you could just use a stored procedure or type the SQL there to populate the Table Adapter.

Once you have added a table adapter to your dataset you can bind your DataGrid to that table adapter just as you would to a regular table.

I know this is probably now what your looking for but the truth is that I came across your question while looking for a way to do more or less the same thing.

2) You table adapter can be based on many tables using either a SQL statement or a Stored Procedure.

3) Why don't you directly bind those controls using their datasource property?

4) If the controls are themselves bound then you can change the data through the controls and to see the changes in your datagrid you should just need to "refresh" (call it's databind() method) to see the updated data.

Comment: If your trying to bind it in code I don't think it's any different then using a table (just use the view in place of a table in the command text).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack.
I was doing in the similar way as you told.


It really resolved my problem, except the control population is done by the individual GridView's selected row's position/index, and then collecting the relative Column's Cell Value and populating to the concerned Control.


Thanks again. Issue resolved.

Comment: @MuzaffarAliRana You should mark this answer as accepted if its solved your problem. Use the marker next to the vote counter of this answer to accept the answer.